# Markdown unable to convert devanagari characters

Tags: command-line, markdown

Running Kubuntu 18.04. markdown (provided by discount 2.2.3).

With a file with only roman characters, `markdown test.md -o test.html` does as expected; produces a test.html file with content as expected.

If test.md contains any devanagari characters, the same command just writes to stdout but does not produce any output file! FWIW, what it writes to stdout is what it should produce in the output file.

What is happening here? How do I set things right?

Comment: Probably a bug, maybe try one of the other markdown parsers, or `pandoc`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with `markdown test.md >test.html` being a workaround.

Comment: @muru Yes. `pandoc` works flawlessly. :)

Comment: @dessert Yes. `markdown test.md >test.html` works flawlessly. This does not help me, however. As I was using emacs to export the markdown documents.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the place for bug reports, I suggest you file a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/discount and https://github.com/Orc/discount instead.